# Boost libraries vc100

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have all boost libraries named with `vc80` for example - `libboost_serialization-vc80-mt-1_42` but the compiler is looking for `libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_42` would i need to re-download the libraries for `vc100` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  You either need to download and install new libraries or build them yourself.

Comment: Thanks, can i build with existing include header files?

Comment: @snoz:  Yes:  There are instructions in the [Boost Getting Startled Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can download precompiled boost libraries from http://boost.teeks99.com/. Version 1.46.1 worked for me. I see they now have 1.47 available as well. They supply files for Visual Studio - VC8 SP1, VC9 SP1, and VC10 (starting with 1.43), 32- and 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Boost doesn't provide compiled libraries, it would be hundreds of megabytes in size if it provided libraries for every compiler, every platform, every target. So you need to rebuild boost libraries as it is described in the introduction.

P.S. Though boost distribution doesn't include compiled libraries, other parties do. For Visual Studio you can get compiled libraries here: http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: Boost does not provide compiled binaries, but BoostPro Computing does.

Comment: But they don't (last I looked) provide x64 binaries.

Comment: @John:  They also don't provide 1.45.0 binaries yet.  IMO, it's better to build your own anyway, that way you can configure the build settings as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

boost uses compiler version built in library name to avoid incompatibility. your have precompiled boost libraries for vc80 = VC8 = Visual C++ 2005. but you use VC10 = Visual C++ 2010, so you need correct library versions. as it was recommended, download them or build yourself